# Apache2 RemoteIP module returns 0.0.0.0 when RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For is set

Tags: apache2.4, x-forwarded-for, apache2-module, google-cloud-proxy

The **Apache** is running behind **Google HTTPS Proxy**. Apache **RemoteIP module** is enabled which seems to work fine. Some requests are flagged in PHP code when **Remote IP is 0.0.0.0**. After investigation it is guessed that for some **X-Forwarded-For IP list** might have 0.0.0.0.
Apache logs prints

```
LogFormat "%V:%p|%a|%{c}a|%{remoteip-proxy-ip-list}n|%{X-Forwarded-For}i|
%a is 0.0.0.0
%{c}a is 35.191.14.79
%{remoteip-proxy-ip-list}n is 35.191.14.79, 34.36.172.235, 193.1.150.232
%{X-Forwarded-For}i remains empty
```

It can happen only when **X-Forwarded-For** is set to **0.0.0.0, 193.1.150.232, 34.36.172.235, 35.191.14.79**

I need to understand how it is possible? 193.1.150.232 looks like **private address** and Remote IP should stop parsing before it and set the remote IP as 34.36.172.235 and not 0.0.0.0
Further how it is possible to have origin of web request as 0.0.0.0?

Comment: I have created a bug for Apache2 https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66678 It would be nice if Google HTTPS Proxy team can also comment that how X-Forwarded-For had 0.0.0.0 as the origin of request?